# Which caster level bonuses stack for overcoming SR?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spell-resistance, caster-level

Which of the following bonuses stack for overcoming SR?

**Master Specialist:**

> **Caster Level Increase:** Upon reaching 6th level, add 1 to your caster level whenever you cast a spell of your chosen school.

**Spell Penetration + Greater Spell Penetration** (explicitly stack together)

> Benefit
>   You get a +2 bonus on caster level checks (1d20 + caster level) made to overcome a creature’s spell resistance.
>
> Benefit
>   You get a +2 bonus on caster level checks (1d20 + caster level) made to overcome a creature’s spell resistance. This bonus stacks with the one from Spell Penetration.

**Orange Ioun Stone**

> +1 caster level

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they do stack. There are unnamed bonuses and, like all unnamed bonuses, [they stack if they don't came from the exact same source](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/theBasics.htm#stacking).

Comment: I was uncertain because of the amount of "caster level bonus" I can find, good to have some conformation.

Comment: That in mind, (adn I dont think I have ever seen it) if you had a +2 insight bonus to caster level, that would not stack with another insight bonus to caster level.